# Grab Frame/Screenshot from SurfaceView while Playing Video

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-bitmap

Some video players like "ExoPlayer" are using `SurfaceView` as a listener to the `VideoEngine`. When doing a screenshot, I am just getting a black image.

Here's how I am creating the screenshot:

```
   public Bitmap viewToBMP(View view) {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap       bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

I've already searched intensively on SO, but there are no relevant answers, only workarounds. Is there a solution?

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Comment: You cannot capture the image from a SurfaceView, but you can intercept the process of drawing on said SurfaceView and get the image using GLES20.glReadPixels